# Error : NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException: Could not instantiate class named NSLayoutConstraint

Tags: ios5, xib, nslayoutconstraint

Developed an application on iOS 6 sdk. I have both iphone and ipad version. I googled for the error message and advised disabled Auto Layout on properties of xib file. It works on iPhone 5.1 but not iPad 5.1. And i cannot figure out the exact issue. Please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using different XIB files for iPhone and iPad. Deselect "Use Autolayout" in the iPad's XIB file as well.

[image: Error : NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException: Could not instantiate class named NSLayoutConstraint - Deactivate AutoLayout]